# Baseurl for a component in all environment

Tags: angular

I have to call a login link in window.open(), where I`ll be giving my return URL as query string parameter which it returns back to that URL. Return URL I have created a separate component for it, a temporary one which show "Please wait". The URL for the component is

```
url = location.origin+ "/milesConfirm"
```

The problem is when I do deployment(normal and prod), it is not coming back to that component. Is there any way to do this with common base url for all environment. Please help..

Comment: can you add more detail about your issue?

Comment: I`m getting return URL, but the problem is prod build can`t go to defined route eg:baseurl/milesConfirm, but it can go to baseurl

Comment: can you show more detail about error message?

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL /paymentuitest/loading was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

You can add setting.json file in assets folder, after ng build go to setting.json change back end url.

```
export class SettingService  {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  public getJSON(file): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get("./assets/configs/" + file + ".json");
  }
  public getSetting(){
      // use setting here
  }
}
```

In app folder, i add folder configs/setting.json

Content in setting.json

```
{
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:52555"
}
```

In app module add APP_INITIALIZER

```
{
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (setting: SettingService) => function() {return setting.getSetting()},
      deps: [SettingService],
      multi: true
    }
```

Refer this link
[Angular: Is it possible to read a json file after building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55061493/angular-is-it-possible-to-read-a-json-file-after-building/55061712)

Comment: But we can`t redirect to sub component in prod environment, Like upto home page we can search, but other component it gives error